# Windows CMD file/folder Compression using 7z or alternative .tar.gz

Tags: windows, compression, cmd, gzip, 7zip

I've searched how to compress files/folders using 7z on windows cmd, I've found the way to compress to: zip, tar, 7z, ..etc but not .tar.gz or .tar.bz2

Here it is the documentation I user: http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

And here is the command I used:

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z "%%X.7z" "%%X\"
```

Change "7z" in both "%%X.7z" "-t7z" to the required extension, and you're ready to get the desired result. But unfortunately this way not applicable to .tar.gz

I need to use gzip compression & don't know how, of course on CMD. Any way? I'm sure there's a way using 7z bot how? If there's alternatives it's OK..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved.  You can accomplish this by writing a CMD batch file with the following contents:

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -ttar "%%X.tar" "%%X\"
for %%X in (*.tar) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tgzip "%%X.gz" "%%X"
```

Note that the double `%` signs should be removed if you're trying to directly execute this within an interactive CMD console.

Comment: This script iterates over subdirs in current dir and packs them to separate archives.

Answer (score 2):

With 7-Zip 9.20 you can avoid the for loop just adding \ at name ends, this works for me:

`set "_dir=%1"`

`set "_7zexe=c:\<my-7z-dir>\7z.exe"`

`"%_7zexe%" a -ttar %_dir%.tar %_dir%\`

`"%_7zexe%" a -tgzip %_dir%.gz %_dir%.tar`

Answer (score 0):

`.tar.gz` is actually two formats.  `TAR` is an uncompressed archive containing multiple files.  `GZIP` is a compressed file containing the single `tar` file.

So you need to do it in two steps on the command line

For example, to add text files to `files.tar.gz`

```
7z.exe a -ttar files.tar *.txt 
7z.exe a -tgzip files.tar.gz files.tar
```

Comment: I know that .tar.gz is two formats, .tar is uncompressed archive, and the .gz is the compressed. But the question still goes, how to do it?

Comment: Can you edit this line to do it pelase: for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z "%%X.7z" "%%X\"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner:

```
7za a dummy -ttar -so @filelist | 7za a pack.tgz -sipack.tar -tgzip -mx9
```

or

```
for /d %%X in (*) do ( 7za a dummy -ttar -so "%%X\" | 7za a %%X.tgz -tgzip -si%%X.tar )
```